# How to get facebook public events of a specific user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to fetch all events of my account or any specific user by its userid.. The below query returns null array.. What is the problem ? If any permission is required, from where i can change it ?

```
SELECT eid, name, pic, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=12345) AND creator=12345
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Permissions

- To get events of the connected user: `user_events`,
- To get events of a friend of the connected user: `friends_events`,
- To get events of a random user: there is no permission, which means that **you can't** get his events.

#### The query

```
SELECT eid, name, pic, creator 
  FROM event 
 WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=12345) 
      AND creator=12345
```

What are you trying to get? This query fetches the events of a user who created an event AND participates to it. The thing is, when a user creates an event, he automatically participates to it.

Let me suggest you two queries:

- Get the events which a user participates to. This will include the events that the user has created.

  `SELECT eid, name, pic, creator 
  FROM event 
  WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=12345)`
- **Only** get the events which a user created:

  `SELECT eid, name, pic, creator
   FROM event 
   WHERE creator=12345`